# Very simple regex to get the numbers in url: http://artige.no/bilde/6908

Tags: php, regex

This is just a really simple regex-question. I'd like to grab the last numbers from a url that looks like this:

```
http://artige.no/bilde/6908
```

The url will always look like this, with a number after /bilde/

Comment: Also `parse_url` and/or `strrchr` could be used.

Comment: and lots more to pick from at http://php.net/strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In which case,

```
~/bilde/(\d+)~
```

Is what you seek. Will find any number of digits after the string `/bilde/`

Comment: For legibility you could use a different RegExp delimiter and for a (very slight) performance increase match the start and end of the string - something like `|^.*/bilde/(\d+)/?$|` ... but otherwise, yup (though check your spelling in the RegExp).

Answer (score 7):

You do not really need a regex for this.

```
$url = 'http://artige.no/bilde/6908';
$num = intval(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1));
echo $num;
```

Comment: @OptimusCrime: "You do not really need a regex" is a polite way of saying "you should not use a regex, unless there's something going on which you are not revealing in which case you should really reveal it up front". I thought that this might be a useful answer, even though it's not what you asked for. Apologies for not being helpful.

Comment: +1 for not using a regex, which for many people is the blind solution to all problems. And +1 for guiding OP into something new. Too bad he won't listen

Comment: @OptimusCrime: Sometimes people offer *alternative* solutions.  You may have been asking for a regex, but you never said why, so that may not be the best answer.  Sometimes there are better ways to do things.

Comment: @Jon: +1 for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = array();
$url = "http://artige.no/bilde/6908";
preg_match('/([0-9]+)$/', $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This uses the pattern `([0-9]+)$` to match one or more digits at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
"(?<=/bilde/)\d+$"
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "http://artige.no/bilde/6908"|grep -Po "(?<=/bilde/)\d+$"
6908
```

as you required, (/bilde/) url like:

```
http://artige.no/NoTWithBilde/1234
```

will not be matched.