# Get id from url in a variable PHP

Tags: php

Have a problem to get the id from the URL in a variable!

The Url is like this `domain.com/article/1123/`

and its like dynamic with many id's

I want to save the 1123 in a variable please help!

a tried it with this

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && !preg_match('/[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}/', $_GET['id'], $id)) { 
        require_once('404.php'); 
    } else { 
        $id = $_GET['id']; 
    }
```

Comment: What was the problem? What did you make to not get it?

Comment: Are you using a framework? If so which one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very simple regex to get the numbers in url: http://artige.no/bilde/6908](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807692/very-simple-regex-to-get-the-numbers-in-url-http-artige-no-bilde-6908)

Comment: @Anant You don't need a Regex for this dude.

Comment: You want to read and learn about request rewriting and search friendly URLs.

Answer (score 8):

The absolute simplest way to accomplish this, is with `basename()`

```
echo basename('domain.com/article/1123');
```

Which will print

```
1123
```

the reference url [click hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395049/get-last-part-of-url-php)

Comment: i want to save the id everytime from the current url not only from one url

Comment: Then pass a variable containing the URL to the `basename(0` function.

Comment: thanks jay blanchard can you give me a example from basename ! and sorry im not so good in php

Comment: <?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Answer (score 4):

I would do in this way:

1. Explode the string using `/`.
2. Get the length of the exploded array.
3. Get the last element, which will be the ID.

**Code**

```
$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url = explode("/", $url);
$id = $url[count($url) - 1];
```

Comment: this is not working for me or i do anything wrong ! :(

Comment: Okay... Did you define the `$url` to be the current URL? @amokkhan

Comment: @PraveenKumar  yes this works perfect with one link and is a good solution from you but i need this with a dynamic url like ' domain.com/article/1123'  and 'domain.com/article/2342/' thanks

Comment: @amokkhan You need to set the URL like `$url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`. It should work as expected, as `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` is dynamic based on your current URL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar   okay thanks that i have to copy it so $url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url = explode("/", $url);
$id = $url[count($url) - 1];

Comment: @PraveenKumar  with 'domain.com/article/1123/' works but with $url = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; it dont work :(((

Comment: @amokkhan What's teh output for `var_dump($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for your time to help me but i dont see anything when i copy this in my file

Comment: i am new in php :D

Comment: @amokkhan At the very beginning of your PHP file, put this: `<?php var_dump($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]); die();` and open the URL and tell me what you see?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  i see this   string(11) "/objekt.php"

Comment: @amokkhan So your URL doesn't look like the dynamic one?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  the objekt.php i have renamed to /articles/{id from article} and the article is dynamic but on the site it have many articles !  only the id is changing

Comment: @amokkhan You shouldn't be doing like that. You should be doing what is called as routing...

Comment: @amokkhan Sorry to ask you again, but are you using any frameworks?

Comment: @amokkhan I am just thinking of what might gone wrong. Can you do this? Set up a C9 and give access?

Comment: @PraveenKumar what is c9 ?

Comment: @amokkhan It's a collaborative JSFiddle kind of application, where you can run PHP and other things. Check out http://C9.io...

Comment: @amokkhan I have requested access. Just check your email or C9.

Comment: @amokkhan You need to click on Run... Only then we can check it. Please click or approve my access. `:)` Should be from `praveen*****ce`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i run it

Comment: @amokkhan Did you approve my request?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i send you a request check your mail

Comment: @amokkhan Yes, you have accepted. Yea, you need the whole code for this to function. Lemme know once you have added the whole directory...

Comment: @PraveenKumar the full project is included now

Comment: @amokkhan Checking.

Comment: @amokkhan Doesn't work mate... :( It is not even loading now.

Comment: yes i see haha you can check it on teamviewer if you wont

Comment: @amokkhan Mate, sure, but no free service ha ha. You can hire me at https://hackhands.com/praveen/... `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely be using `parse_url` to select the correct portion of the URL – just in case a `?query` or `#fragment` exists on the URL

```
$parts = explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

$parts[0]; // 'domain.com'
$parts[1]; // 'article'
$parts[2]; // '1123'
```

You'll probably want to reference these as names too. You can do that elegantly with `array_combine`

```
$params = array_combine(['domain', 'resource', 'id'], $parts);

$params['domain'];   // 'domain.com'
$params['resource']; // 'article'
$params['id'];       // '1123'
```

---

I'm really feeling like a procrastinator right now so I made you a little router. You don't have to bother dissecting this too much right now; first learn how to just use it, then you can pick it apart later.

```
function makeRouter ($routes, callable $else) {
  return function ($url) use ($routes, $else) {
    foreach ($routes as $route => $handler) {
      if (preg_match(makeRouteMatcher($route), $url, $values)) {
        call_user_func_array($handler, array_slice($values, 1));
        return;
      }
    }
    call_user_func($else, $url);
  };
}

function makeRouteMatcher ($route) {
  return sprintf('#^%s$#', preg_replace('#:([^/]+)#', '([^/]+)', $route));
}

function route404 ($url) {
  echo "No matching route: $url";
}
```

OK, so here we'll define our routes and what's supposed to happen on each route

```
// create a router instance with your route patterns and handlers
$router = makeRouter([

  '/:domain/:resource/:id' => function ($domain, $resource, $id) {
    echo "domain:$domain, resource:$resource, id:$id", PHP_EOL;
  },

  '/public/:filename' => function ($filename) {
    echo "serving up file: $filename", PHP_EOL;
  },

  '/' => function () {
    echo "root url!", PHP_EOL;
  }
], 'route404');
```

Now let's see it do our bidding ...

```
$router('/domain.com/article/1123');
// domain:domain.com, resource:article, id:1123

$router('/public/cats.jpg');
// serving up file: cats.jpg

$router('/');
// root url!

$router('what?');
// No matching route: what?
```

Yeah, I was really *that* bored with my current work task ...

Answer (score 1):

That can be done quite simple. First of all, you should create a variable with a string that contains your URL. That can be done with the `$_SERVER` array. This contains information about your server, also the URL you're actually at.

Second point is to split the URL. This can be done by different ways, I like to use the p_reg function to split it. In your case, you want to split after every `/` because this way you'll have an array with every single "directory" of your URL.

After that, its simply choosing the right position in the array.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /article/1123/
$folders = preg_split('/', $path); // splits folders in array
$your_id = $folders[1];
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard `preg_split`?

Comment: That's pretty much like `explode()`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard `preg_*` functions are used for **P**erl **Reg**ular Expressions...

Comment: I know @naomik, but the cost here is no more than `explode()`

Comment: @JayBlanchard that's not the contested point; You were saying there is no regex, but there *is*

Comment: *Fair enough* @naomik

Answer (score 1):

To be thorough, you'll want to start with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$parts=parse_url("domain.com/article/1123/");
```

That will give you an array with a handful of keys. The one you are looking for is path.

Split the path on / and take the last one.

```
$path_parts=explode('/', $parts['path']);
```

Your ID is now in `$path_parts[count($path_parts)-1];`