# How to have a post variable defined without '?{name}=' in the url?

Tags: php, apache

Currently on my website, my profile urls look like this:
../user/?id=1

I would rather them look like this:
../user/1

How would I go about this? I'm running this with Apache and PHP if that is important to the question.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263261/get-id-from-url-in-a-variable-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get id from url in a variable PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263261/get-id-from-url-in-a-variable-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with .htaccess
Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This htaccess rule will redirect input like [www.site.com/user/123](http://www.site.com/user/123) to user.php?id=123